# Is it possible to automatically bound unbounded functions to something different than `window`?

Tags: javascript

Suppose I want to run some Javascript code, how can I change it's global context in a way that even unbounded functions defined inside it get bounded to this new context? My current idea is the following:

```
(function() {
  var window = {foo: 'bar'}; // just an example

  (function() {
    // PUT CODE HERE
  }).call(window);
})();
```

This works for simple things. Both the context of the inner function and the `window` object will point to the variable I declared:

```
(function() {
  var window = {foo: 'bar'}; // just an example

  (function() {
    // <CODE>
    console.log(this, window);
    // </CODE>
  }).call(window);
})();
```

The output is what I expected: `Object {foo: "bar"} Object {foo: "bar"}`.

But when the inner code defines a function without specifying its `this` object (e.g. doesn't use `Function.prototype.bind`), it automatically gets the original `window` object as `this`. Check the following code and its output:

```
(function() {
  var window = {foo: 'bar'};

  (function() {
    // <CODE>
    console.log(this, window);
    (function() {
      console.log(this, window);
    })();
    // </CODE>
  }).call(window);
})();

// This code outputs:
Object {foo: "bar"} Object {foo: "bar"}
Window {external: Object, chrome: Object, document: document, configData: Object, speechSynthesis: SpeechSynthesis…} Object {foo: "bar"}
```

Is there a way of truly isolate a piece of code of getting access to the original `window` object?

Comment: "Is there a way of truly isolate a piece of code of getting access to the original window object?" One could always access window using `var global = Function('return this')();`

Comment: @YuryTarabanko That should be the answer (ie "no").  Even if the outer function here is put in strict mode (which does stop the innermost `this` from getting it), that still works to get hold of the `window` in the innermost function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use strict mode, when you function is called without a defined context (new, bind, call, apply). This will be undefined, so it can't modify the global object window.
I recommand you to read [mozilla documentation about strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#Securing_JavaScript). Where you will find the following sentences:

> That means, among other things, that in browsers it's no longer
>   possible to reference the window object through this inside a strict
>   mode function.

To convince yourself, you can try this code in a browser:

```
function useStrictMode() {
  'use strict';
  console.log(this);
}

function noStrict() {
  console.log(this);
}

useStrictMode(); //log undefined
noStrict(); //log window
```

Putting 'use strict' at a beginning of a file will make all the content of your file use it. But it can have issue if you concate your js file with other files. In fact, 'use strict' can change comportment of some code and break some libraries. This is one of the reasons why it's always recommended to wrap all your code in a anonymous function:

```
(function(){
  'use strict';

  //your code go here, function declaration here will use strict mode to
})();
```

Comment: To be specific, add `'use strict';` as the first line within the first function. Doing so gives output of: `Object {foo: "bar"} Object {foo: "bar"}` ...
`undefined Object {foo: "bar"}`

Comment: @RaulFernandez ideally `'use strict';` should be within the function so that it doesn't affect global scope. Using strict mode globally can cause issues with 3rd party code.

Comment: @MatthewHerbst: *Ideally*, every code complies with strict mode :-)

Comment: @Bergi true, but I'd prefer web pages that run over trusting others to believe in our ideals :D